# SpecialFolder.Personal access and location on each device

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi I created app with Sqlite. Everything works good but I cant find location of database on my phone.
Next step is to create saving excel files with DB tables...everything works fine, I've created alert to debug and files are creating well.

But I cant find db file and excel file on my phone and even on PC after connecting via USB.

Path to saving everything is:

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

Comment: What kind of phone?  Are you using the proper tools?  You should use XCode to look at the iOS filesystem, and adb to look at Android

Comment: Xiaomi Redmi Note 5

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found solution for me. I've added code to the MainActivity

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.SetVmPolicy(builder.Build());
```

Now I try to open xlsx by default app.